Odoo 16 - ValueError: External ID not found in the system: web.assets_backend
I have Odoo 16 up with docker-compose and I´m trying to create some charts with Highchart but I keep getting "ValueError: External ID not found in the system: web.assets_backend" when importing the assets. Does anyone know what´s wrong?
This are the assets in my views.xml
<template id="assets_account_dashboard" name="Account Dashboard" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
     <xpath expr="." position="inside">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/digital_twin/static/src/js/dashboard.js"/>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="digital_twin/static/lib/Highchart/code/highcharts.js"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/digital_twin/static/src/css/style.scss"/>
     </xpath>
</template>

And this is my manifest
{
    'name': "digital_twin",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "https://www.yourcompany.com",

    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'digital_twin/static/src/js/dashboard.js',
        ],
    },

    'depends': ['base'],

    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/predictive_analisis_views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],

    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}

I have tried changing the inherit_id to 'website.assets_backend', 'web.assets_frontend', 'website.assets_frontend', but I keep getting the same error even though its referenced in the manifest. I also have the developer mode (with assets) active in Odoo.

Have you tried adding web as dependency in the manifest file?

Yes, I have tried 'depends': ['base', 'web'] but I still get the same error

Have you tried to regenerate the assets bundle (using the the top bar 'Bug' icon)?

{
'name': 'Super Man',
'version': '1.0',
'category': 'Uncategorized',
'license': 'LGPL-3',
'author': '',
'website': '',
'depends': ['portal', 'contacts'],
'data': [
    'views/cloth_view.xml',
    'wizards/settlement_wizard_view.xml',
    
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    
    'views/menu.xml',
],
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        '/superman_j/static/src/component/**/*.js',
        '/superman_j/static/src/component/**/*.scss',
    ],
    'web.assets_qweb': [
        '/superman_j/static/src/component/**/*.xml'
    ],
}

}
you can follow this structure and check module name is correctly define in path reference.  i hope it will help you thanks.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
